# SQL Server Geography - Find International Dateline and Equator

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

In SQL Server, I want to find if geography intersects/crosses the international dateline and equator.

I thought of the below logic but am not sure if it is the right way of doing this.

- Geography crossing international date line: if the coordinates of the international date line fall within the given coordinates then it seems to cross the dateline
- Geography crossing the equator: if any of latitude from the given coordinate is <= 0 then it seems to cross the equator

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is come up with linestrings that represent the Equator and International Dateline (respectively). From there, you can use `STIntersects()` against your `geography` data to test for intersection.

---

Addendum - here are naïve definitions of the equator and International Date Line (IDL). The equator works around what appears to be a technical limitation in SQL Server's geography implementation regarding antipodes while the IDL uses the simple but incorrect definition of "longitude -180°".

```
DECLARE 
    @e GEOGRAPHY = geography::STMLineFromText('MULTILINESTRING ((-179.9999 0, 0 0), (0 0, 179.9999 0))', 4326),
    @idl GEOGRAPHY = geography::STMLineFromText('MULTILINESTRING ((-180 0, -180 90), (-180 0, -180 -90))', 4326);
```

Comment: Can you please share the linestrings that represent the Equator and International Dateline. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ReyanChougle - I've added an addendum to my answer to address your question.